# unexpected bourne shell script output of case statement

Tags: sh

I am trying to find executable files. Trying to use bourne shell `/bin/sh` for greater portability. Below script `echo`s everything with `find:` at beginning of string.

```
#!/bin/sh
DIRS=`find / -perm -4000`
for DIR in "$DIRS"
do
  case "$DIR" in
    find:*);;
  esac
done
```

QUESTION) Why is it echoing for `find:*)` when no commands are given?

If i add `*) echo "$DIR";;` clause to the case statement, it will echo the files that are executable for current user, this is all i really want, but isn't happening (i haven't scripted for `/bin/sh` really, but this has bewildered me)

Yeah `sed`, `awk`, `cut` can help immensely, but some of these commands most likely will not be available (why aren't they available. because they might not be!) so i thought a bourne shell version is more portable. Maybe there is a better way for `/bin/sh` substring matching, any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The lines that you are trying to get rid of presumably look like this:

```
find: `/root': Permission denied
```

That's an error message. The command substitution

```
`find ...`
```

only captures output, not errors. You need to add a redirection to include the errors:

```
`find ... 2>&1`
```

Also, `-perm 4000` is the setuid bit, not an executable bit.

Comment: yeah meant to say setuid. forgot to redirect errors, duh. its been a while since i scripted, thanks for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can put `find` directly in the for loop

```
for DIR in `find / -perm -4000`
```

Comment: yes i can. old habits die hard. time to update my shell scripting skills hey, they are extremely dull!